# phpQuery не находит таблицу по классу

Tags: phpquery

На странице сайта имеется следующая таблица:

```
<table cellpadding="4" width="100%" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="topper">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span onclick="(function() {vart=document.getElementById(&#39;trBirthday&#39;);
                    if(t.style.display==&#39;none&#39;){t.style.display=&#39;&#39;;}
                    else {t.style.display=&#39;none&#39;;}})();" style="cursor:pointer;color:white;"><b>
                    Дни рождения: <font color="green">Прошло: 7</font> / 
                    <font color="red">Сегодня: 1 !!!</font> / 
                    <font color="orange">Завтра: 6</font> / 
                    <font color="blue">Скоро: 34</font></b>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td width="450" align="right" style="white-space:nowrap;">
                <span class="orange">Вошли&nbsp;как:&nbsp;USER</span>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<span class="tabs">выйти</span></a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<img src="./Товары [2018-09-30 09_57_54]_files/uoff.gif">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

При помощи phpQuery пытаюсь ее спарсить, но результат выводит всю страницу. Что делаю не так? Код ниже:

```
function get_content($url){
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $doc = phpQuery::newDocument($content);
    $elem = $doc->find('.topper');
    return $elem;
}
```

Comment: нет и у Вас ошибок до строки `$elem = $doc->find('.topper');`, в `$content` или `$doc` ? что возвращает `$elem` ?

Comment: код представляет собой функцию, которая возвращает $elem - в данной переменной хранится результат поиска, но в моем случае почему-то не таблица, которую я пытаюсь найти, а вся страница

$content - хранит данные, которые возвращает функция file_get_contents (то есть содержимое страницы в строке)

$doc - объект созданный phpQuery

Comment: также хочу добавить, что если вместо таблицы искать на этой странице текстовое поле по id тогда все работает нормально, что в свою очередь подтверждает, что с $content и $doc все в порядке..